# How to run a python program from c++

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x, c++11

I am trying to make a program in c++, but i cant make the program because in one part of the code I need to run a python program from c++ and I dont know how to do it. I've been trying many ways of doing it but none of them worked. So the code should look sometihnglike this:`somethingtoruntheprogram("pytestx.py");` or something close to that. Id prefer doing it without python.h. I just need to execute this program, I need to run the program because I have redirected output and input from the python program with sys.stdout and sys.stdin to text files and then I need to take data from those text files and compare them. I am using windows.

Comment: `#include <windows.h>` and then you have choice of doing `system('py program.py')` or `CreateProcess()` or `ShellExecute()` and many more. This honestly is very broad topic and each method has it's own advantages and problems.

Comment: the POSIX way to do it is with fork/exec: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exec_(system_call)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two way of doing that:

- Use `system`/`fork` and `exec*`/...
- Embed a python interpreter in your program (cf [python 2.6 doc](https://docs.python.org/2/extending/extending.html#calling-python-functions-from-c) or [boost.python](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/python/doc/html/index.html))

Using a embedded interpreter is (IMHO) the best way to do it because it gives you more control over the execution of the script, because it's not OS-dependant and it does not rely on your target having a python interpreter (configured as you require).

Comment: yes, I linked the 2.6 doc for python because that's the first link that I found, but every python version has a way (more or less identical to the other version) to embed an interpreter in C code. Boost add a C++ wrapper. Both boost and python work for the OS where python is ported.

Comment: [Cython](http://cython.org) is also worth mentioning, especially if you're looking for perfomance.

Answer (score 0):

There's POSIX `popen` and on Windows `_popen`, which is halfway between `exec` and `system`. It offers the required control over `stdin` and `stdout`, which `system` does not. But on the other hand, it's not as complicated as the `exec` family of functions.